# Redirect to the last page requested after login with Jasig CAS

Tags: spring-mvc, cas

I'm using Jasig CAS in a Spring application. The configuration of the CAS Authentication Filter bean looks like this:

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="casServerLoginUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"/>
  <property name="service" value="https://localhost:8443/myapp/index.html"/>
</bean>
```

I.e. on the one hand the authentication filter will redirect to the url specified in `casServerLoginUrl` property and on the other hand the CAS server will redirect back to the url specified in `service` property.

Is there a way to make the value of `service` property dynamic? I would like it to contain the last requested url before login and respectively to  redirect to this url after successful login with CAS.

Comment: did u find out a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *`service`* parameters on client side when you call the cas login page

```
https://yourcas.com/cas/login?service=urlservice
```

CAS redirect the client to this URL upon successful authentication

Comment: yes, but how to make this parameter to be dynamic, i.e. to take different values (not only one constant value)?

Answer (score 1):

As the service parameter identifies the the service on CAS-Server, it can't be dynamically be changed.
The issue is that the CAS server uses the service parameter for identification AND as redirect location url.

If you manipulate the service/redirect-URL in the 'CasAuthenticationFilter' so that your client application sets the service parameter to the currently requestes url, then cas would create a ticket for that specific url.
That means 1. the ticket validation will fail and 2. Cas-Server create a new ticket for each requested page on the Client-Application.